# Webpack: Separate production and dev builds

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack, build-system

I have recently started to evaluate webpack. Having used grunt previously I am used to the fact that I can start grunt with various parameters to configure what is going to happen during the build. For example:

```
grunt watch
```

would run a debug build and enable the watch task. While:

```
grunt build
```

would trigger a fully minimized production build that has all development specific functionality disabled.

I am wondering if **webpack** has a similar feature that lets me easily switch between different configurations. I have done some research already but I did not like the approaches I have seen so far:

- I saw a suggestion to specify `NODE_ENV=production` before calling `webpack`, but this is not platform independend (e.g. does not work on windows).
- Using the `-p` switch, but that seems to only affect minimization
- Using a separate config file for webpack, but I would prefer a solution where I do not have to maintain two separate files.

I understand that *webpack* is not actually a task runner such as *grunt* or *gulp*, but rather a *module bundler*. But its being promoted as a replacement for *grunt* or *gulp* [see this Medium.com Blog](https://medium.com/javascript-and-opinions/state-of-the-art-javascript-in-2016-ab67fc68eb0b).

What I would really like to see is the ability to get a development build with something like `webpack watch` and a production build with `webpack` or `webpack build` is that possible with webpack

Comment: Glad to see that question. I am struggling with the same problem and can't really find good article about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you use webpack-dev-server it is quite easy to understand you are in dev mode:

```
let isDevMode = process.argv[1].endsWith('webpack-dev-server') || process.argv[1].endsWith('webpack-dev-server.js');
```

First condition is for Linux / mac, the second is for Windows.

and then use this to configure your files.

If you are not using dev server you can pass any parameter while running the webpack as you would do with any nodejs script (I use [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) to read the parameters but it is just a sugar, don't use if you don't need to):

```
let argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

let isDevMode = argv.dev; // or watch or whatever you want to pass
```

and then call it that way:

```
webpack --dev
```

This is actually a very flexible way of doing lots of things, not only specifying dev mode. I use it also to specify bundle names, etc. The only thing you need to care about is avoiding using the parameters which are served by webpack itself.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that I had such easy access to the process environment, a quick `console.log(process)` reveals that its actually pretty to get access to all kinds of things from the webpack process. One question though, you propably meant to write `process.argv[2].endswith('webpack...')`, on my system `argv[1]` is `webpack`, while `argv[0]` is `nodejs`

Comment: Nope, it's exactly `argv[1]` because the `webpack` will be replaced by `webpack-dev-server` if you use the webpack dev server (it's a separate executable with another name).